# XRCed learning resources?

Tags: wxwidgets, xrc

I've seen many people saying [XRCed](http://xrced.sourceforge.net/) very strong "if you have learned how to use it". Unfortuntately, there're few documents about it, and many of the links on SF.net home page is 404 now.

The best I can found is [XRCed Tutorial](http://wiki.wxpython.org/XRCed%20Tutorial), however it is too primitive - so, does anyone have some idea for where can I find better documents about it?

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion; have you tried [wxFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/)? XRCed seems a little outdated (hasn't been updated for a while), and it does the same thing as wxFB. I've been using wxFB for a while in several projects and it's a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

Alongside the already mentioned wxFormBuilder, I'm going to throw in [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/), as well. While I prefer wxFormbuilders GUI, I found it to be lacking in the available widgets. So I moved to wxGlade based on the amount of widgets it offers.

Both can create XRC files (and some other codes like C++ and python) and I think both are actively maintained. I think XRCed hasn't been updated since 2007.

For ease of use, I would go with wxFormBuilder. If you want to use various different widgets, for the moment, go with wxGlade. I don't know if wxFormbuilder is planning on incorporating ToggleButtons and the like in their future releases. It isn't in the one that I am using...